How do you generate a PowerShell script from manually crafted AST nodes?
The title pretty much says it. I’m trying to write a ICustomVisitor to manipulate a PowerShell AST and then generate a script from the AST. I’ve been using an EmptyScriptExtent object as the IScriptExtent value for my AST node constructors for any new nodes that I insert into the tree. The ScriptBlockAst.ToString method appears to reference the Extent under the hood, which in my case is empty.
Looking through the source code, I couldn’t find anything that looked like a AST to string generator.
Does anyone know if the PowerShell SDK provides this functionality by default or if there are any open source libraries that can generate PowerShell code from a PowerShell AST?
Here is what I have so far:
[Test]
public void AstToString() {
    //IScriptExtent? extent = new ScriptExtent(
    //new ScriptPosition(null, 0, 0, null),
    //new ScriptPosition(null, 0, 0, null));

    Type type = typeof(IScriptExtent).Assembly.GetTypes()
        .Where(x => x.Name.Contains("EmptyScriptExtent"))
        .First();

    IScriptExtent? extent = (IScriptExtent?)Activator.CreateInstance(type);
    ClassicAssert.IsNotNull(extent);

    ScriptExtent empty = new ScriptExtent(null, null);

    List<CommandElementAst> elements = new List<CommandElementAst>();
    elements.Add(new StringConstantExpressionAst(extent, "gci", StringConstantType.BareWord));
    elements.Add(new StringConstantExpressionAst(extent, "C:\\", StringConstantType.SingleQuoted));

    CommandAst command = new CommandAst(extent, elements, TokenKind.Unknown, new List<RedirectionAst>());

    StatementBlockAst statements = new StatementBlockAst(extent, new StatementAst[] { command }, new TrapStatementAst[0]);

    ParamBlockAst parameters = new ParamBlockAst(extent, new AttributeAst[0], new ParameterAst[0]);

    ScriptBlockAst block = new ScriptBlockAst(extent, parameters, statements, false);

    string text = block.ToString();
    text = this.GetSerializedString(block);
    text = block.GetScriptBlock().ToString();
    ClassicAssert.IsFalse(string.IsNullOrEmpty(text));
}

private string GetSerializedString(ScriptBlockAst block) {
    MethodInfo? compile = typeof(ScriptBlock)
        .GetMethods(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic)
        .Where(x => x.Name.Equals("Compile"))
        .Where(x => x.GetParameters().Length == 1)
        .FirstOrDefault();
    ClassicAssert.IsNotNull(compile);
    ScriptBlock sb = block.GetScriptBlock();
    compile.Invoke(sb, new object[] { false });
    return sb.ToString();

    //MethodInfo? toStringForSerialization = typeof(ScriptBlockAst)
    //    .GetMethods(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic)
    //    .Where(x => x.Name.Equals("ToStringForSerialization"))
    //    .Where(x => x.GetParameters().Length == 0)
    //    .FirstOrDefault();
    //ClassicAssert.IsNotNull(toStringForSerialization);

    //return (string)toStringForSerialization.Invoke(block, null);
}

The issue is that the text variable is always empty, and I can't figure out how to generate a PowerShell script from this AST.

The AST maps source code to an expression tree - if you handcraft an AST by constantly mapping empty extents to expressions that that's what you end up with: an empty string mapped to an expression tree :) To compile+execute the resulting tree: block.GetScriptBlock().Invoke()

I've added some code to try compiling the ScriptBlock, but it still yields an empty string.

That's the expected behavior - the textual representation of the "code" (the empty extent) you've provided during AST Construction is an empty string. You can implement your own visitor that generates equivalent source code if that's what you want, but there's no "GenerateEquivalentSourceCode()" method available out of the box

I was worried that would be the case. I’m not looking forward to writing and testing an AST to code generator lol.

You can get some help from static helper methods exposed by [System.Management.Automation.Language.CodeGeneration], but yes, there will be a painful amount of code to write for this...
